# Integrating on a Riemann surface

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-integration

I would like to understand how one integrates on a simple example of a Riemann surface: $\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda$ is a lattice. As an example, how does one calculate $$ \int_{\mathbb{C}/\Lambda} f(z) dz $$ for some meromorphic function $f$ ? How does one identify it with some double integral on $\mathbb{R}$ or so ? If anyone has some illustrative example that would be very nice.

Comment: You can't integrate the 1-form $dz$ on a (real) surface, only on a (real) curve. On a surface you can integrate the 2-forms $dx \wedge dy$, $dz\wedge d\overline{z}$. Concretely $\int_{[0,1]+i[0,1]} g(x,y)dx \wedge dy$ is just a chart independent version of $\int_0^1\int_0^1 g(x,y)dxdy$